# Save copy of file on server every day

Tags: php

I have a simple html page that adds entries to a json file that's on the server via ajax php. I would like to add a few php lines to make sure that every night at 11:59:59, it saves a backup of the original file on the server (ideally inside a folder called backup).

So far here's what I have in php. It's basically just opening a json file, adding an entry and saving. I want to make sure to have a backup file for everyday at 11:59:59 that gets saved to a backup folder on the server.

```
    <?php
    $theuser = $_POST['theuser'];
    $thecontest = $_POST['thecontest'];
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];


        $json = file_get_contents('alldata.json');
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $flag = false;
        foreach($data as $d){
            if($d['username'] == $theuser && $d['contest'] == $thecontest){
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    if (!$flag){
        $data[] = array('username'=> $theuser, 'contest' => $thecontest, 'timestamp' => $timestamp);
        file_put_contents('alldata.json', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
        $msg = "yes";
    }else{
        $msg = "no";
    }

    echo $msg;die;

?>
```

Comment: You need a Cron job for that since PHP can't run on demand by itself at a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about what privileges you have on the server or what environment you're in, but what you want to do is run this script via a [cron job](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800).

You will be able to set exactly the time and frequency you want to run the script, and then execute it on a schedule. But you need to have access to the server itself, as this is NOT a functionality of php, but of your server. There is no way to do this natively in PHP unless you did something ridiculous like an infinite loop that constantly checked the time, but this would timeout anyway and I only share it as an example.

I'd suggest you read up on cron jobs and then if you have a specific question about how to implement them, let me know and I'll be happy to try and help.

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting at godaddy and found the cron jobs section in the admin panel. I added the following line to be executed every day. Let me know if it makes sense.

0 0 * * * cp /calendrier/alldata.json /calendrier/backup

Ideally, I would like to have a timestamp at the end of each file that gets copied to the backup folder.